# How can i get the current date and number of signed up users in Adonis JS

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am working on this adonis js project and i am trying to get the current date and time and also display the total number of registered users.

Comment: In laravel you use {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}} which displays Tuesday, 30 June 2020 at 09:54 PM how do you get the current date and time also in Adonis Js or Node?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, do you want to recover the moment when a user was authenticated?

If so, I believe that the easiest solution would be to create a new column in the user table and when authenticating, you will change its value. Something like:

```
class UserController {

  async login ({ request, auth }) {
    const { email, password } = request.all()
    await auth
          .attempt(email, password)
          .then(async token => {
            const user = await User.findBy('email', email)
            user.last_login = moment()
            await user.save()}
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return { success: false, error }
    })

    return 'Logged in successfully'
  }
}
```

`last_login` would be the new column.

To recover the number of registered users, just make a count in the user table:

```
await User.query().getCount()
```

Both solutions are generic and fit for any framework

Comment: if you want to get current date on laravel you use ```{{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}}``` what i am trying to get is the current date and time

Comment: In laravel you use {{ now()->format('l, d F Y \a\t h:i A')}} which displays Tuesday, 30 June 2020 at 09:54 PM how do you get the current date and time also in Adonis Js or Node?